# MQTT-SN using any encryption?

Tags: mqtt

Does MQTT-SN provide any encryption like AES-128 etc.? As I know, it's using a simple binary encryption but in my opinion this cannot be seen as a security feature. Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MQTT-SN doesn't supply any encryption at a protocol level, but you are free to encrypt the payload yourself how ever you want.

Also since MQTT-SN doesn't make any requirements on what transport is used to carry the packets, but you could build a system that uses [DTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security) (similar to how CoAPS works)

Comment: But with using DTLS the size of the header is increasing, that's why it is not really useful for big applications (50k+ sensors). That is the reason why I am searching for an alternative... Thanks anyway!

Comment: with 50k+ sensors on the same LAN segment you are going to have way more other problems

Comment: I'm talking about industrial IoT where the carrier provides the infrastructure and the sensors are connected via NarrowBand-IoT to the cell (from there on it is just a software issue). Many thanks for your help!